# Migrate from apigateway to apigatewayv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

How to migrate from apigateway to apigatewayv2 using AWS-CDK?

Specifically: I am using `LambdaRestApi` and `restApiId` and `deploymentStage` from that resource.

```js
    // old
    const apiGw = new apigateway.LambdaRestApi(this, 'MyAPI', {
      handler: lambdaFrontend,
      proxy: true,
      binaryMediaTypes: ['*/*'],
    });

    // new
    const apiGw2 = new apigateway.CfnApi(this as any, 'MyAPIV2', {
      protocolType: "http",
      target: lambdaFrontend.functionArn,
    })
```

I am trying to get the OriginSource for CF like so:
`const domainName = ${apiGw.restApiId}.execute-api.${this.region}.${this.urlSuffix};`

**First question:** How can I retrieve the `domainName` with ApiGW2?

I also need the stageName. Currently I am retrieving it like so:
`const originPath = '/' + apiGw.deploymentStage.stageName;`

**Second question:** How can I retrieve the origin Path with ApiGW2?

Alternatively: Is there a better way to connect my ApiGW2 with CF?

```js
    const fecf = new cf.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, "MyCF", {
      originConfigs: [{
        customOriginSource: {
          domainName: `${apiGw.restApiId}.execute-api.${this.region}.${this.urlSuffix}`,
        },
        originPath: '/' + apiGw.deploymentStage.stageName,
      ...
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can now be solved quite easily since we have official documentation for this now.
If anybody out there wants to migrate to V2 now, this is the way:

```js
    const httpApiIntegration = new apigatewayv2Integrations.LambdaProxyIntegration({
      handler: fn,
    });
    const httpApi = new apigatewayv2.HttpApi(this, "MyApiV2");
    httpApi.addRoutes({
      path: "/",
      methods: [HttpMethod.ANY],
      integration: httpApiIntegration,
    });

    new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, "MyCf", {
      defaultRootObject: "/",
      originConfigs: [
        {
          customOriginSource: {
            domainName: `${httpApi.httpApiId}.execute-api.${this.region}.${this.urlSuffix}`,
          },
          behaviors: [
            {
              isDefaultBehavior: true,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      enableIpV6: true,
    });
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-readme.html

Steps:

- create an integration (e.g. a lambda function), this comes from a dedicated package (apigatewayv2-integrations)
- create an HttpApi, no options needed
- New: Opposed to APIGWv1 you will have to add route handlers for your paths (httpApi.addRoutes).
- Cloudfront config is very similar

Comment: Hey 1 question, how can you pass the lambda Alias to the LambdaProxyIntegration?

Comment: And also how to put in StageVariable for the Api stage? By using ApigatewayV2